# why does a simple Python/Haskell/etc program freeze/hang when doing an import?

Tags: haskell, scripting, imagemagick, sh, python-import

Why does this Python program freeze/hang:

```
$ ls -l freeze.py
-rwx------ 1 rick rick 24 Oct 27 11:40 freeze.py
$ cat freeze.py
import re
print "hello"
$ ./freeze.py
  C-c
```

And why does this Haskell program also freeze/hang:

```
$ ls -l freeze.hs
-rwxrw-r-- 1 rick rick 46 Oct 27 11:22 freeze.hs
$ cat freeze.hs
import Text.Regex.Posix
main = print "hello"
$ ./freeze.hs
  C-c
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(I know this is a rudimentary/rookie mistake. But I doubt that I'm the first or last person to make this mistake ...so I'll document it here so future klutzes like me can google it.)

These scripts freeze because they are actually shell scripts. These shell scripts are actually running the `import` command-line program ... which is provided by the [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) package:

```
$ sh freeze.hs
  C-c
$ which import
/usr/bin/import
$ man import | head -10
... import - saves any visible window on an X server and outputs it as an image file.
$ import screenshot.ps
    ... and here notice the mouse icon changes to a cross-hair icon ...
    ... so then press the mouse button to finish this operation ...
$ file screenshot.ps
screenshot.ps: PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, Level 1
```

So my kudos to the ImageMagick crew for providing a nice, silent command-line operation.

At least on various Linux-based operating system, these scripts trigger operation of the `import` command-line program. BSD, Windows, MacOS, etc may respond differently.

Here is **correct** operation of the script with the Python interpreter and `ghc` compiler:

```
$ python freeze.py
hello
$ runghc freeze.hs
"hello"
```

Or alternatively, include the `#!` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
$ ls -l no_freeze.py
-rwx------ 1 rick rick 46 Oct 27 11:44 no_freeze.py
$ cat no_freeze.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
print "hello"
$ ./no_freeze.py
hello
```

And the same for Haskell:

```
$ ls -l no_freeze.hs
-rwx------ 1 rick rick 68 Oct 27 11:26 no_freeze.hs
$ cat no_freeze.hs
#!/usr/bin/env runghc
import Text.Regex.Posix
main = print "hello"
$ ./no_freeze.hs
"hello"
```

On my MacOS computer, I'm getting this error because some part of my X11 setup isn't finished. For those who didn't install X11, I imagine you would get the *command not found* error.

```
$ import screenshot
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.5-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-07-02 http://www.imagemagick.org
...
import: delegate library support not built-in `' (X11) @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1297.
```

Comment: Have you found a way to introduce a shell syntax error before the import statement? I would like to do just that in some of my scripts.

Comment: Some ideas come to mind. First, maybe we can add something to `~/.profile` file ... can profile access the contents of a subsequent script (when not interactive)? Second, replace `sh` with something to first checks the head of script for `import`. But, to my mind, the cleanest solution would have `import` command output a text prompt like "Click mouse button to save screenshot". Then add a `--quiet` flag for silent operation. Really, this confusion is a big coincidence between the start of Python/Haskell and ImageMagick. I can imagine other keyword/command interactions from other languages.

Comment: None of the scripts are executed for non-interactive use. With bash, you could use an exported function (yuck) called `import` to override the command. But at this point, it is probably easier to put `~/bin` on your path and have a fake `import` program there.

Comment: Why would you want a syntax error? Put a shebang at the top of the script if you intend to run it as one so your shell/OS knows what interpreter to use.

Comment: I do use shebang but in this situation I was creating a minimal script. Once we become practiced enough, then shebang becomes a reflex ... and I have macros to generate them. But I suppose @Florian maybe be considering protection for newbies. Overall, it is better to have a system that provides timely error messages. Then again, the only way to gain experience is to make mistakes.

Comment: The shell does provide timely error messages; you just don't have any errors in the script (or aren't reaching them) because you have a program named `import` installed. This is a basic operational issue: if you want to run a script as a standalone executable, it *must* have a shebang to specify the correct interpreter to use.